# Predicting Optimized Value of Target Variable using Machine Learning when historical target variable itself is not the optimized

Tags: machine-learning

Question is quite related to fundamentals of machine Learning
- Its a prediction problem
- `

> Model is predicting Target variable as per historical records with
>   RMSE of 0.01  COD of 0.97 and MAE of 0.7

`
- But the predicted Target value is not Optimized one as per client.
- As per them Historical records doesn't have the Optimized value of target variable and there is a scope to get that optimized value

My question is as Historical Target value observations itself are not optimized then, how will Machine Learning algorithm predict optimized value?

- If there is a way, then which is that approach.
- Optimization techniques we can use to minimize the error, but will it also help in predicting optimized value.

Comment: From what I am understanding, if the data is not accurate, then you cannot really expect the prediction to be accurate. You could throw in some heuristics (something akin to assumptions...) to try and mitigate the error, but this can cause more problems that it will solve...

Comment: Basically their requirement is predicting Optimized value of target, as actual past historic target data is not the optimized one. To give example say Act Target - 56 degF , Pred Target is 56.5 DegF, But Optimized Target value they are expecting is arounf 58 DegF (They have some assumptions and theory behind it ofcourse)